# How to insert an image on Pentaho dashboard with condition?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I know how to insert an image using `add image` avaible on `Layout Panel` or using HTML.

However I want to make a condition : If the image is not avaible or doesn't exist, there is a default image I want to display.

So I think I need to do it with js function.
What is the best way for it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use image tag in html for that.

```
 <img id="img" src="SomeImage.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src=default.png" alt="" width="100" height="120">
```

Comment: You mean <img src="..."></img> ? If I am not wrong, with image tag, there's no way to do if condition.

Comment: you can check with onerror check out my updated answer.

Comment: what you want in if condition.? if image is not available and if you want to display default image then this works . i checked it in html page.