# How to upload an image on Pentaho dashboard ? ( variable, condition, local path)

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I want to display an image depending on parameter called "ca_code" on dashboard.

All the images are in a repository of my current theme ( I know that you can also upload images to server, must be easiler but I need to keep this), here's an example of an image path:

> D:\pentaho\pentaho-8-2\pentaho-server\pentaho-solutions\system\common-ui\resources\themes\sapphire\img_project\CA120.jpg

Here, 120 is a ca_code. I get this ca_code as variable by `query component`.
Here's what I tried on `Post Fetch` of `query component`:

```
function f(ca_code) { 
var ca_code=ca_code.resultset;

var img = '<img src="../common-ui/resources/themes/sapphire/img_project/CA'+ca_code.resultset+'.jpg/content"/>';

var img_default='<img src="../common-ui/resources/themes/sapphire/img_project/CA000.jpg/content"/>';

document.getElementById('ca_logo').innerHTML=img;

}
```

And it doesn't work, think it is the path prob.

When I used HTML on Layout Panel, the path was fine, the image was displayed but I can't do on HTML because I need variable ca_code, I want to do it on `Query Component - Post Fetch`.

And also, how to check if the image exists ? If it doesn't exist, I want to display img_default.

Any help would be nice !

Comment: I think the resultset is an array, so ca_code.resultset[0][0] might work better. Also, I've never seen /content AFTER the filename for an image, but I assume it works when you try it statically.

Comment: As you have declared **ca_code=ca_code.resultset** do not write  write .resultset in img url. for default img check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57678223/how-to-insert-an-image-on-pentaho-dashboard-with-condition    also there is no issue in **/content** declaration.

Comment: Hi! I checked your answer, tried it as well. But since I get the image URL with the result var of query component ( dynamic image), I don't know how to precise the image path on html code. This html is on layout panel, right ?

Comment: But you already defined it in your function. remove this line **var ca_code=ca_code.resultset;** and try it.